# Book about a girl with magic and a boy a with curse

Tags: story-identification, magic, witches

The book starts with the girl who is the main protagonist entering a new town during a storm. Upon entering the town she has an accident (caused by her book having a reaction with an unknown force when entering town lines) where she meets the boy with the curse (that she doesn't know about at the time). Later, both the boy and girl find out they go to the same school and start to talk and get to know each other. The girl meets another girl with white hair, whose life force has been tampered with.

The boy's girlfriend is found out to be a witch that placed a curse on his family that allows her to stay young if there is someone alive from that family but they slowly go insane the older they get. There's something about binding a non-magical person to a witch and that what the girl and the girl with the white hair end up trying to do but it fails. It ends up working with the boy with the curse. There's also something about it now working for males that are conceived of a man or something like that. Which doesn't aply to the boy because he was a in vitro fertilization baby.

Comment: I found the story. Its called spellcaster by Claudia Gray

Comment: Consider writing a [self-answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) to give more visibility to your finding.

Answer (score 4):

Just so that we have an answer, Kedar identified it above as *[Spellcaster](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12700790-spellcaster)* by Claudia Gray. If they come back and write an answer, I will gladly remove mine.

> When Nadia’s family moves to Captive’s Sound, she instantly realizes there’s more to it than meets the eye. Descended from witches, Nadia senses a dark and powerful magic at work in her new town. Mateo has lived in Captive’s Sound his entire life, trying to dodge the local legend that his family is cursed - and that curse will cause him to believe he’s seeing the future … until it drives him mad. When the strange dreams Mateo has been having of rescuing a beautiful girl—Nadia—from a car accident come true, he knows he’s doomed.
>
> Despite the forces pulling them apart, Nadia and Mateo must work together to break the chains of his family’s terrible curse, and to prevent a disaster that threatens the lives of everyone around them. Shimmering with magic and mystery, New York Times bestselling author Claudia Gray’s new novel is sure to draw fans of the Hex Hall and Caster Chronicles series, and fans of the hit CW TV show The Secret Circle.

Comment: Funnily enough, I recently started reading the *Hex Hall* books, not remembering I'd posted this.